# Showing classes to user and instantiating selected type

Tags: vb.net, reflection, combobox

I'm starting to learn about Reflection in VB.NET, and I have a little example problem I'm working on to understand some concepts.

So I have one interface implemented by three classes:

```
Public Interface IVehicle
    Sub SayType()
End Interface

Public Class Bike
    Implements IVehicle
    Public Sub SayType() Implements IVehicle.SayType
        MsgBox("I'm a bike")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Car
    Implements IVehicle
    Public Sub SayType() Implements IVehicle.SayType
        MsgBox("I'm a car")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Plane
    Implements IVehicle
    Public Sub SayType() Implements IVehicle.SayType
        MsgBox("I'm a plane")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I would like the user to select one type of vehicle of all the vehicles available, instantiate one object of this type and call its method "SayType".

So, with this situation, I have 2 questions

**The 1st one**: I have thought about filling one ComboBox control with all the classes which implement the interface IVehicle. I have searched how to do so with reflection, and I've came up with this solution:

```
    Private Function ObtainVehicleTypes() As IEnumerable(Of Type)
        Dim types As IEnumerable(Of Type) = _
            Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetTypes.Where(Function(t) _
            t.GetInterface("IVehicle") IsNot Nothing)
        Return types
    End Function
```

With those types, I fill the ComboBox like this, which also works fine:

```
Private Sub AddTypesOfVehicles()
    Dim types As IEnumerable(Of Type) = ObtainVehicleTypes()
    For Each t As Type In types
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(t.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that, when I try to retrieve the item selected by the user and obtain the type asociated like shown below, I get Nothing, since the String doesn't contain the AssemblyName, only the Class name:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim type As Type = TryCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, Type) 'Here I get Nothing
        Dim v As IVehicle = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(type), IVehicle)
        v.SayType()
End Sub
```

I have also tried to to add this to the combobox:

```
For Each t As Type In types
   ComboBox1.Items.Add(t) 'Adding the type, not only its name.
Next
```

But then it displays the AssemblyName to the user, which I want to avoid.

So, the question is... how would you do to show the classes to the user and the retrieve them correctly to instantiate an object of the chosen class?

**The 2nd question**: Do you consider this as a good approach? Would you suggest something simpler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand the need of the method `SayType` on the interface. All types implements the `GetType` method which will return the info you'll need.

```
Dim vehicles As IVehicle() = New IVehicle() {New Bike(), New Car(), New Plane()}

For Each vehicle As IVehicle In vehicles
    MsgBox(String.Format("I'm a {0}", vehicle.GetType().Name.ToLower()))
Next

'This will produce:
'------------------
'I'm a bike
'I'm a car
'I'm a plane
'------------------
```

This is how you could populate the combobox:

```
    Dim t = GetType(IVehicle)
    Dim list As List(Of Type) = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(Function(x As Type) ((x <> t) AndAlso t.IsAssignableFrom(x))).ToList()
    Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = list
    Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

And to retrieve the type:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles saveButton.Click
    If (Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1) Then
        Dim t As Type = TryCast(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem, Type)
        If (Not t Is Nothing) Then
            MsgBox(t.FullName)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit**

A more real-world example of an `IVehicle` interface would be something like:

```
Public Interface IVehicle

    ReadOnly Property Manufacturer() As String

    ReadOnly Property Model() As String

    Property Price() As Decimal

End Interface
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I haven't tought about this way of populating the combobox, and it works just fine. About the interface, it was the most simple method I thought for testing the rest of the code, of course it's of little use in a real application.

Comment: Good! And as @lomed pointed out, if you only want classes implementing the interface, add `x.IsClass = True`in the clause: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(Function(x As Type) ((x <> t) AndAlso t.IsAssignableFrom(x) AndAlso x.IsClass)).ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

combobx problem its Excellent answered by @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå.

Here are additional improvements:
ObtainVehicleTypes:

```
Private Function ObtainVehicleTypes() As IEnumerable(Of Type)
    Dim IVehicleType = GetType(IVehicle)
    Dim types As IEnumerable(Of Type) = _
        Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetTypes.Where(
        Function(t) IVehicleType.IsAssignableFrom(t) AndAlso t.IsClass = True)
    Return types
End Function

Private Sub AddTypesOfVehicles()
    Dim types As IEnumerable(Of Type) = ObtainVehicleTypes().ToArray()
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = types
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim type As Type = TryCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, Type) 
    Dim v As IVehicle = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(type), IVehicle)
    v.SayType()
End Sub
```